# Height of pseudo content property Increasing when I decrease the width of Parent Element, why?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a star rating system & I want to display half stars if rating is 4.5 or 3.5 or 2.5 and so on. For example, if rating is 4.5, then I want to show 4 and half gold stars and rest grey star. It is just like we see in the e-commerce website.

I am using pseudo::before element with content property to display the stars through CSS. When I decrease the width of parent element to show the gold stars, the height of content property is increasing automatically & it is not showing the half star. How to do that, please somebody answer. Thanks in advance.

```css
.grey-stars {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #b5b5b5;
  height: 55px;
}

.grey-stars::before {
  content: '\f005  \f005  \f005  \f005  \f005';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.gold-stars {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: gold;
}

.gold-stars::before {
  content: '\f005  \f005  \f005  \f005  \f005';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<div class="grey-stars">
  <div class="gold-stars" style="width: 85%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How you adding stars? Can you share your font awesome link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

Use `white-space: nowrap;` to **gold-stars** class

More info : visit [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Here i given `width="50%"` that is **2.5 rating**

[image]

```css
.grey-stars{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #b5b5b5;
    height: 55px;
}
.grey-stars::before{
    content: '\f005  \f005  \f005  \f005  \f005';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.gold-stars{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: gold;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.gold-stars::before{
    content: '\f005  \f005  \f005  \f005  \f005';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<div class="grey-stars">
    <div class="gold-stars" style="width: 50%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: display property not have ruby value, where have you find it?

Comment: Also what is the difference in Font Awesome CSS and Font Awesome JavaScript? I used `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` but it not worked :(

Comment: I used font awesome 5.

Comment: ruby property is mentioned on [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) but not on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_class_display.asp), where should I can find real specification?

Comment: I updated answer `white-space: nowrap;` use to fixed the issue.

Comment: @RayeesAC Awesome! Thanks. white-space: nowrap; property is the perfect answer to my question. It is working for me as the way I wanted...